# Cual es la diferencia de los conceptos "Estilo de Arquitectura" y "Patron de Arquitectura"?

Tags: ingenieria-del-software

Cual es la diferencia de los conceptos "Estilo de Arquitectura" y "Patron de Arquitectura"? Por ejemplo, se dice que REST es un estilo de arquitectura mientras que MVC es un patron de Arquitectura.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no está dentro de la temática del sitio según se ha discutido en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/822

Answer (score 4):

El MVC (Modelo-Vista-Controlador) es un patrón de diseño, más que de arquitectura, pero en cualquier caso las diferencias son:

### Estilo Arquitectural:

- No es necesario que exista un problema concreto a resolver para que se cree un estilo.
- Crea un marco de referencia a la hora de definir conceptos: si piensas en REST tienes en mente conceptos como *recurso*, *sin estado*, métodos HTTP (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH) y su semántica, pero no te define cómo implementarlos (puedes usar MVC o no, por ejemplo). Otro ejemplo sería SOA (Arquitectura orientada a servicios).

### Patrón arquitectural:

- Como todos los patrones de diseño, están enfocados a resolver un problema concreto.
- Define los pasos a seguir para resolverlo: el patrón MVC, por ejemplo, te dice que tienes que tener un Modelo, una Vista y Controladores claramente definidos, además del rol esperado de cada uno. El patrón *Cliente-Servidor* te define dos partes bien diferenciadas y cómo debe ser la comunicación entre ellas.

Por usar una analogía *de arquitectura*, tienes los estilos gótico, románico... pero el patrón es la forma de resolver un problema general presente en las construcciones  (por ejemplo, el cómo resolver la instalación eléctrica, o de las tuberías de agua, cumpliendo con la normativa legal).